# pHow to replace \n line break between specific tag in XML

Tags: php, xml, preg-replace

i have a very long XML source file stored in $Result which contains amongst other tags, multiple tags named uid1 and uid20.

```
<set1> 
  <uid1>Line 1
      Line 2
      Line 3
      Line 4
  </uid1>
  <uid20>Line 1
      Line 2
      Line 3
      Line 4
  </uid20>
</set1>
<set2> 
  <uid1>Line 1
      Line 2
      Line 3
      Line 4
  </uid1>
  <uid20>Line 1
      Line 2
      Line 3
      Line 4
  </uid20>
</set2>
 ...
```

I need to replace all \n line breaks between those two tags with a semicolon, but leave all other \n line breaks untouched. I tried preg_replace and could not get it to work, beacuse i could not figure out how to include an array of tags. As well i read the preg_replace is not ideal for doing that? Any hints for me?

Comment: So whats wrong with processing it like an XML Document and using `str_replace()` on only the nodes that you want to mess with

Comment: just use `SimpleXML` or `DOM`, get those node values and edit accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `str_replace("</set1>\n<set2>", "</set1>;<set2>", $xml);`

\n will only work in double quotes btw.

See here https://3v4l.org/ltmWq

Comment: OK, but what if i have <uidx>some text with line breaks</uidx> in my <set> and i don´t want those line breaks to be changed?

Comment: @chicky they won't be removed. That snippet specifically searches between </set1> and <set2>.Look here, I added some linebreaks https://3v4l.org/1cHuj